# Integrating out heavy fields while preserving symmetries

Tags: quantum-field-theory, effective-field-theory

The basic a-b-c for integrating out heavy fields what one learns when making the example of Fermi theory, is that if you have a Lagrangian
$L= -\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}+\frac{1}{2}M^2 V^\mu V_\mu + g J^\mu V_\mu$
It is straight forward to integrate out the heavy field $V$ at tree level: you just take the equation of motion, neglecting the kineti term:
$M^2 V^\mu + g J^\mu =0$, solve for $V$ and plug it back in the original lagrangian, getting $L = -\frac{g^2}{2}\frac{J^\mu J_\mu}{M^2} = \frac{G_F}{\sqrt{2}}J^\mu J_\mu$.
This is easily extended in the caes of a scalar mediator as well. Let's now instead suppose to have 2 or more particles that mix with each other, and this particles are charged under some gauge group. Let's suppose they are scalars to simplify the approach. We will have a lagrangian like
$L= - m_{11} S_1^\dagger S1 - m_{22} S_2^\dagger S_2 - m_{12}(S_1^\dagger S_2 + S_2^\dagger S_1) + y \bar{q}q S_2$ plus kinetic terms and higher order terms in the potential. 
Let's assume that we know that the mixing $S_1, S_2$ will be small, as $S_2$ will be much heavier than $S_1$, and that $S_1$ will get a non zero vacuum expectation value, while $S_2$ will not. It is possible to integrate out the field $S_2$ without rewriting the lagrangian in the broken phase, thus spoiling the nice gauge invarianze it has?